# Eclipse Oxygen: set cursor color (to black)

Tags: java, centos7, gnome, eclipse-oxygen

After an update my Eclipse Oxygen picked white for a cursor color, which makes it almost invisible. So, instead of doing my work, I'm spending a Monday morning trying to get it back to normal - black, that is.

There are possible workarounds, like making the line background color darker, but I want to fix in a regular way.

I'm using CentOS 7.3 + Gnome. OS was also recently updated, and there were changes to the appearance. So I'm not sure, is it about OS or Eclipse. Tagging both.

Have someone had the same issue and fixed it?

Comment: Is this a programming question @badbishop?

Comment: @MacStevins: Not exactly, of course. It is a question about an IDE, which is mainly used for programming and by programmers. So programmers IMHO are more likely to know the answer. Given there are another 110556 questions tagged "eclipse", I took the liberty to ask it here.

Comment: oh i forgot that IDEs can be questioned here, because I've rested 2 years and came back noob in this site.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to reproduce the issue on a VM. It worked fine, thus narrowing the problem to specific hardware and drivers.

Solved it by installing the vendors graphic card driver (NVIDIA), replacing nouveau. There is a bunch of pages describing the process, here is one:

http://www.advancedclustering.com/act_kb/installing-nvidia-drivers-rhel-centos-7/

So, it is not really a Stackoverflow question. If only I knew beforehand :).